# Pronunciation of the syllables that are long by position

Tags: pronunciation

I have a question about pronunciation of long/heavy syllables:

Should we lengthen the syllable that is long by position (e. g. septem)

Also, should we lengthen the syllable which contains diphtong (long by nature) (Caecilius)

I'm interested only about pronunciation, not so much about terms (heavy/long).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by lengthening a syllable? I would say that the syllables called long are the ones that have naturally longer duration due to containing more than single consonant and a short vowel. What is the difference, to you, between a short vowel and a long one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If syllables that are long by position also always had long vowels, there would be no reason to distinguish "long by position" from "long by nature". **If a syllable is *only* long by position, the vowel is short.** *Septem* is /ˈseptem/ [ˈsɛptɛ̃], not /ˈseːptem/ [ˈseːptɛ̃].
This potential confusion in students surrounding the term "long by position" is actually exactly why most modern textbooks use "heavy" and "light" for syllables instead. The fact that some older dictionaries sometimes used macrons to mark vowels in syllables that were merely long by position surely won't have helped.

(It's obviously possible for syllables to be long by position and by nature both. A well-known example is that in the sequence *-Vns(-)* or *-Vnf-* (where *V* is any vowel), the vowel is always long (and probably nasalised), and while the *-n-* was not generally pronounced except perhaps in a few cases where it was restored from the spelling, in cases where it was (such as *consul*, for probably most speakers), the syllables containing these vowels were long both by position and by nature.)

Diphthongs are inherently long, i.e. two morae in length: the vowel part is effectively one mora and the glide is another (if that's how you choose to analyse them). Combined, they're the length of a normal long vowel and no longer; e.g. *aes* is [ae̯s], not [aːe̯s]. Some languages have overlong (trimoraic) diphthongs, but Latin is not one of those.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful!

Comment: What's your evidence that the 'n' was rarely pronounced?

Comment: @bobsmith76 Epigraphic evidence (in the Old Latin period the *n* was often not written, with *cosol* and *cesor* being common for Classical *consul*, *censor*; in the Classical period spelling was less variable, but the *n* was still optional in e.g. *totie(n)s*, *vicie(n)s*), occasional non-etymological hypercorrections (*thensaurus*), the lack of reflexes in Romance languages (Vulgar Latin lost the nasalisation of vowels), and, for *consul* specifically, the explicit claim of Quintillian that the *n* was not pronounced (*et 'columna' et 'consules' exempta n littera legimus*).

Comment: @bobsmith76 Some educated speakers restored the pronunciation of the *n*s and some of those restorations possibly made their way to the general public, but Velius Longus claimed even Cicero said *foresia*, *Megalesia*, and *Hortesia* rather than *forensia*, *Megalensia*, and *Hortensia*.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answers.